# How can I determine the ProductCode for the included products in my WiX ManagedBootstrapperApplication at runtime?

Tags: wix, burn

I have a managed bootstrapper application with a bundle that includes four products.  Each of the products are defined with `"*"` for the Id and have a unique UpgradeCode.

In my managed bootstrapper, I need to get the ProductCode (GUID) for the products that are part of my bundle.  The detect event handlers' event args (such as `DetectPackageCompleteEventArgs`) have a `PackageId` value which is the name of the msi (ex: the "Common.msi" package has a `PackageId` of "Common.msi").

I also checked the  BootstrapperApplicationData.xml file, which has the `ProductCode` and `UpgradeCode` of the bundle itself, but not in the `WixPackageProperties` nodes for the individual products.

In the case of a related package being detected (upgrade), the `ProductCode` is included in the `DetectRelatedMsiPackageEventArgs`, but that event doesn't fire when the running the installer for the currently-installed version (ie: clicking "Modify" on Add/Remove Programs)

**How can I determine at runtime in my MBA what the ProductCode is for the included products?**

Additional info:

Ultimately, I'm using the product code to get the `ARPINSTALLLOCATION` value using `MsiGetProductInfo(productCode, "InstallLocation", strbuffer, len);`  This is specifically for the case where the user is "modifying" an existing installation (ie: running the same installer version as an already installed bundle -- not an upgrade) and I need to determine the folder to which they installed originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: The product code isn't provided to the BA. But an explicit registry entry (for example, following the ["remember property pattern" that Rob discusses](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern)) is going to be more reliable and easier to implement than ARPINSTALLLOCATION/MsiGetProductInfo.

Longer answer: Burn runs detection the same way in all "modes" but explicitly doesn't send package-level detection messages when the version of the package in the packages is the same that's installed on the machine.

The place for this kind of static data is in the BA manifest but in v3.8 it doesn't include the product code. Please [file a feature request](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/).

Comment: The feature request was implemented and the current location is https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4233